# How do i write an array to a csv such that each element in the array is in one cell and they are arranged in a row using python?

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have an array named genrelist that contains all the different genres of a movie. How do i write them out to the csv such that each element in the genrelist is in one cell and they are in a row instead of a column in Python 3.6?

Currently, i can write them out in a column by using this code:

```
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    csvFileWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    for genre in genrelist:
      csvFileWriter.writerow([genre])
    csvFile.close()
```

This will produce an output of:

|shonen|

|action|

|Adventure|

Desired output: |shonen| |action| |adventure|

Comment: If you want the list to be one row, why are you breaking it up and building new lists for each item as a separate row? Just *don't do that*.

Comment: writerow will write rows, you for a single row you'd need `csvFileWriter.writerow(genreList)`

Comment: ah newbie mistake.. csvFileWriter.writerow(genreList) is the correct ans.!!

Answer (score 0):

The for loop writes the single genre to a row, like you desire, but you initiate a new row every single time! This makes the multiple rows seem like a column. Your desired output can be generated by printing the entire `genreList` with the `writerow` function. Like so:

```
with open('data.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
csvFileWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
csvFileWriter.writerow(genreList)
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The module pandas happens to have a really nice read_csv() function and also a df.to_csv function.

What you would do is create a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(read_csv('data.csv'))
```

to change the columns to rows, just use:

```
df.transpose()
```

and then you can write it to a file like this:

```
df.to_csv('transposeddata.csv')
```

The full documentation can be found here:

[Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)